# Dynamic columns in sql Join condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql

```
Customer

customer_id |   customer_name | customer_city | customer_number
---------------------------------------------------------------
   1        |   john          | sanjose       | 978234
   2        |   chris         | newyork       | 293
   3        |   mary          | madrid        | 342943
   4        |   tom           | bangkok       | 8627093
---------------------------------------------------------------

Data

data_id |   data_name  |    data_city   |   data_number |   data_cust_id |  customer_id
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    |   abc        |    xyz         |   990         |   1        |  NULL
   2    |   john       |    sanjose     |   978234      |   1        |  NULL
   3    |   mary       |    madrid      |   8627093     |   3        |  NULL
   4    |   tom        |    LA          |   7729        |   4        |  NULL


ActionType

action_id | action_description
-----------------------------------
1         | customer_name
2         | customer_number
3         | customer_city


DataToAction

id |    data_id | action_id
--------------------------
1  |    1       | 1
2  |    1       | 2
4  |    2       | 1
5  |    2       | 2
6  |    2       | 3
7  |    3       | 1
8  |    3       | 2
9  |    4       | 1
```

There are 4 tables -

1. Customer - Has customer datails
2. Data - Raw data pulled from an external source (has customer data and others)
3. ActionType - Has the column names which will be used in a join condition
4. DataToAction - For each of the raw data row in Data table, the columns to be used in the join is specified here.

**Objective** - To populate customer_id in 'Data' table.
I need something like this

```
UPDATE D
SET D.customer_id = C.customer_id
FROM Data D
INNER JOIN Customer C on D.data_cust_id = C.customer_id
WHERE *("GET THE COLUMNS TO BE MATCHED FROM DATATOACTION TABLE AND USE HERE")*
```

For eg., for Data id 1, i will update customer_id based on customer_name & customer_number, for data id 2 i will udpate customer_id based on customer_name, customer_number & customer_city and so on.

How do I apply the dynamic column conditions in the where clause for each of the row wherein the columns to be matched are specified in a different table.

Comment: check this article http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html

Answer (score 0):

Well the question is quite unclear. Can u elaborate the final resulset. 
Purpose of ActionType table??

`UPDATE D`
  `SET D.customer_id = C.customer_id`
  `FROM Data D`
      `INNER JOIN Customer C on D.data_cust_id = C.customer_id`
      `INNER JOIN DataToAction DA ON DA.data_id = D.data_id`